# Laravel 6 call controller method with arguments from routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm trying to call a controller method with arguments from inside routes.php.

In my routes.php:

```
Route::get('/login', function ($reseller, $tld) {
    return view('auth.login', ['reseller' => $reseller, 'tld' => $tld]);
});
```

How can I rewrite the

```
return view('auth.login', ['reseller' => $reseller, 'tld' => $tld]);
```

to use a controller method?

My attempt:

```
return App::call('LoginController@showLinks', ['reseller' => $reseller, 'tld' => $tld]);
```

And in my LoginController:

```
public function showLinks($reseller, $tld)
{
    $showForgotUserLink = false;
    if ($tld == 'foo' || $tld == 'bar') {
        $showForgotUserLink = true;
    }
    $showLangLink = ($tld !== 'baz' && $tld !== 'foobar');
    return view('auth.login', ['showForgotUserLink' => '$showForgotUserLink', 'showLangLink' => '$showLangLink']);
}
```

But I'm getting an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Is these data passed from URL? if not why passing them from routes.php it isn't a place to store static values

Answer (score 1):

Do like that:

routes:

```
Route::get('/login/{reseller}/{tld}', 'LoginController@showLinks')->name('login.show_links');
```

redirect from method:

```
return redirect()->route('login.show_links', ['reseller' => $reseller, 'tld' => $tld]);
```